# Pandas Assign column by partial string match size to array dimension error

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

```
  Postcode         Country
0  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom
1  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom
2  CF5 3EG  United Kingdom
3  DG2 9FH  United Kingdom
```

I create a new column to be assigned based on a partial string match:

```
mytestdf['In_Preston'] = "FALSE"

mytestdf

  Postcode         Country In_Preston
0  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom      FALSE
1  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom      FALSE
2  CF5 3EG  United Kingdom      FALSE
3  DG2 9FH  United Kingdom      FALSE
```

I wish to assign the column "In_Preston" by a partial string match on "Postcode". I try the following:

```
mytestdf.loc[(mytestdf[mytestdf['Postcode'].str.contains("PR2")]), 'In_Preston'] = "TRUE"
```

But this returns the error *"cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 2"*

I look at my code again and believe the issue is that I am selecting a slice of the dataframe from a slice of the dataframe. As such I change to

```
mytestdf.loc[(mytestdf['Postcode'].str.contains("PR2")]), 'In_Preston'] = "TRUE"
```

but my interpreter tells me this is incorrect syntax, though I do not see why.

What is the error in my code or my approach?

Comment: `mytestdf.Postcode.str.startswith('PR2')` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need remove inner filter:

```
mytestdf.loc[mytestdf['Postcode'].str.contains("PR2"), 'In_Preston'] = "TRUE"
```

Another solution is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mytestdf['In_Preston'] = np.where(mytestdf['Postcode'].str.contains("PR2"), 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
print (mytestdf)
  Postcode         Country In_Preston
0  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom       TRUE
1  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom       TRUE
2  CF5 3EG  United Kingdom      FALSE
3  DG2 9FH  United Kingdom      FALSE
```

But if want assign boolean `True`s and `False`s:

```
mytestdf['In_Preston'] = mytestdf['Postcode'].str.contains("PR2")
print (mytestdf)
  Postcode         Country  In_Preston
0  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom        True
1  PR2 6AS  United Kingdom        True
2  CF5 3EG  United Kingdom       False
3  DG2 9FH  United Kingdom       False
```

EDIT by [`comment of Zero`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987604/pandas-assign-column-by-partial-string-match-size-to-array-dimension-error/46987617#comment80922024_46987604):

If want check only start of `Postcode`:

```
mytestdf.Postcode.str.startswith('PR2')
```

Or add regex `^` for start of string:

```
mytestdf['Postcode'].str.contains("^PR2")
```

Comment: Answer works with a number of alternative options for improvement as well. Excellent response, many thanks for your help.